# How can I execute a command from Typescript and output to cmd prompt

Tags: typescript, command, child-process

I would like to execute a command from inside a typescript file.

- The typescript file doesn't have to continue, ideally it would end.
- The command and all its output would be output to screen, as if it was run from command prompt.

I have tried this without success

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec
exec('npm run start', (err, stdout, stderr) =>console.log(stdout));
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [`spawn`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options):

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process')

spawn('npm run start', [], { shell: true, stdio: 'inherit' })
```